# Cannot convert from '_int64' to 'Data *'

Tags: c++, class, time, struct, converters

In my project i have a class to work with time, it's declared like this:

```
class Data {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int hora;
    int minuto;

    public:
       Data();
       Data(int, int, int, int, int);
       Data(const Data &);
       void mostraData();
       void ImprimeData();
       Data operator-(const Data &aux);
};
```

dia = day, mes = month, ano = year, hora = hour.... (portuguese)

And at certain point i have to calculate the difference between two differente times. So i made this simple operator -:

```
Data Data::operator-(const Data & aux){
    Data temp(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    temp.dia = this->dia - aux.dia;
    temp.mes = this->mes - aux.mes;
    temp.ano = this->ano - aux.ano;
    temp.hora = this->hora - aux.hora;
    temp.minuto = this->minuto - aux.minuto;
    return temp;
}
```

Now, I was just testing to see if it calculates the right time, I wrote this peace of code:

```
aux = new Data;
Data *teste = new Data(7, 7, 2016, 22, 41);
Data * resultado = teste - aux;
resultado->ImprimeData();
```

Ps. the function "ImprimeData()" is to print the result.
But on the third line it gives me an error. First it says that a value of tipo 'long long' cannot be used to initialize an entety of type 'Data *', and then it says that cannot convert from _int64 to Data *.

Comment: Why would you expect that data type conversion should be OK?

Comment: There are several issues in the line `Data * resultado = teste - aux;`. The subtraction operator doesn't expect either operand to be a pointer and doesn't return a pointer.

Comment: Stop. If `aux` and `teste` are pointers, why doesn't this code compile? It is a correct syntax (not semantics). What is `aux`?

Comment: @ilotXXI, it's because he's subtracting two pointers and trying to assign that (int64) value to a pointer without a cast. However, that is a red herring since what he's actually trying to do is to call his `operator-` overload. For that he needs to use my answer below.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Pointer - pointer == pointer. No casts needed. What is wrong with a **formal** syntax?

Comment: @ilotXXI. Wrong. `Pointer - Pointer = int`

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz `ptrdiff_t`, not exactly `int` (error says about `_int64`). Isn't it casted to `T *` implicitly? If no, is it related to pointers unsignedness? Or to cast useless?

Comment: @ilotXXI, `__int64` is a Microsoftism, which is a type of `int`. No, the result is not implicitly casted to `T*`. It's an integer difference. Say you had a pointer `void* X` pointing at memory location 987654 and another `void* Y` pointing at memory location 987650. Now the difference of `X - Y` is 4. So if that were implicitly casted to `void*` then it would be "pointing" at memory location 4. Which is most likely not what you want. So, the result of a pointer difference is an `int`.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz `_int`**64**. Not a `_int`**32**.
Ok, you win. Shame on me : ) And `Y - X` is negative that could lead funny things. Thank you for discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
Data * resultado = teste - aux;
```

should be

```
Data resultado = *teste - *aux;
```

The first is subtracting two pointer values. The second is calling your `operator -` overload.

You should also change

```
resultado->ImprimeData();
```

to

```
resultado.ImprimeData();
```

Comment: If i do that it appears an error on the first pointer, in " *teste", saying that cannot convert from 'Data' to 'Data *'

Comment: @CésarPereira, because you also need to remove the `*` from the `Data * resultado`

Comment: That did the job. But then i get an error trying to print the result time. In the line "resultado->ImprimeData()" , i get a "expression must have a pointer type". That is refering to "resultado"

Comment: `.` instead of `->`. What you are doing wrong is a wrong C++ learning.

Comment: @CésarPereira, of course, just change the `->` to a `.` on that line like my edit above shows.

Comment: @ilotXXI, no need to be insulting. Just help the noobie out. He'll get it.

Comment: You're right, forgot about that. 
But hey, i got something i never got before, doesn't have to do with this post but you can try and help anyway xD so, no errors anymore on that calculation, but when i try to run the program i get error saying "precompiled object not linked in; image may not run". What is this? :o

Comment: @CésarPereira, Sorry, I'm not familiar with that error message. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ay26wa2.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Your teste is a pointer, as is your aux.

Which is a bit off since my testes would be considered more a container and/or factory.